# Trying to dynamically load scripts in the page using getScript()

Tags: jquery, json, getscript

I'm building a site which has 2 requirements, the site cannot use any backend code and the site must show a different translation depending on the users country. I solved these issues by using JSON to pull all the data in and HTML5 and Javascript to figure out the Geolocation. However I seem to be falling at what I expected to be a very simple hurdle:

I am using the JQuery getScript() function to load the JSON file into the page and then echoing out the data using html(), however it is not working here is the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var countryName = 'england'.toLowerCase();  
            $.getScript('elements/'+countryName+'/data/datafile.js', function(data) {
                $('.welcomeOne h1').html(data.dt_welcome[0].Translation);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

As you can see, the path to the file has to be dynamic (otherwise I'd just use a standard  tag to include the JSON file). I am not getting any errors but anything I put in the callback for getScript() is simply not being executed, I have tested the file path and I can assure you that it is correct.

BTW here is the relevant snippet of JSON (if it helps)

```
var dt_welcome = [
{"ID":1,"Source":"WELCOME","Characters available":null,"Current Characters":null,"Translation":"WELCOME","Notes":null},
{"ID":2,"Source":"","Characters available":230,"Current characters":210,"Translation":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure","Notes":null},
{"ID":3,"Source":"<Image choices to follow>","Characters available":null,"Current characters":null,"Translation":"","Notes":null},
{"ID":4,"Source":"SEMINAR FINDER","Characters available":null,"Current characters":null,"Translation":"SEMINAR FINDER","Notes":null},
{"ID":5,"Source":"","Characters available":260,"Current characters":234,"Translation":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure test test test test test test","Notes":null},
{"ID":6,"Source":"ENTER NOW","Characters available":null,"Current characters":null,"Translation":"ENTER NOW","Notes":null},
{"ID":7,"Source":"<Please put an 'x' in column F if your country stocks any of the below brands>","Characters available":null,"Current characters":null,"Translation":"","Notes":null},
{"ID":8,"Source":"Brand name","Characters available":null,"Current characters":null,"Translation":"x","Notes":null},
{"ID":9,"Source":"Brand name","Characters available":null,"Current characters":null,"Translation":"","Notes":null},
{"ID":10,"Source":"Brand name","Characters available":null,"Current characters":null,"Translation":"x","Notes":null},
{"ID":11,"Source":"Brand name","Characters available":null,"Current characters":null,"Translation":"","Notes":null},
{"ID":12,"Source":"Brand name","Characters available":null,"Current characters":null,"Translation":"x","Notes":null}];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the contents of your console.log

Comment: My console.log is empty. It doesn't return anything at all.

Comment: I've still not managed to work this out guys, any other ideas?

Comment: Just a thought - maybe you should drop `data` from `data.dt_welcome[0].Translation` as the js will have executed already, meaning the variable `dt_welcome[0].Translation` has been assigned - nothing to do with the `data` you passed to the callback function...

Comment: Also - you could try adding your variable to the global namespace somehow - like `window.dt_welcome = [ ... ]` and see if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not going to execute any code in the javascript file I would go with getJSON instead of getScript

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Remove "var dt_welcome =" from the datafile.js and return only the literal array.

in the call to getJSON you are passing in the argument "data". Use it.

```
   $(function() {
        var countryName = 'england'.toLowerCase();  
        $.getJSON('elements/'+countryName+'/data/datafile.js', function(data) {
            $('.welcomeOne h1').html(data[0].Translation);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you :), I have switched to that, I still appear to be having the same issue though.

Comment: This ended up working. Turned out the reason it wasn't working yesterday was because there were comments in my JSON file. Turns out they are not allowed. Once I'd removed the comments as well as the variable and traililng ';' it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Move this

```
 console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                $('.welcomeOne h1').html(data.dt_welcome[0].Translation);
```

to datafile.js, jQuery automatically runs what it gets from the server as javascript.

EDIT

```
 console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                $('.welcomeOne h1').html(dt_welcome[0].Translation);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't possible, the datafile is something that we will be getting data entry people to edit so we can't include any essential javascript in there, it has to be data only.

Comment: If the js files contains just json you can use $.getJSON

Comment: I updated my answer based on your edit, since what you get from the server will be run by jquery you will get a variable named dt_welcome, you can just access it like a variable you declared on the document.

Comment: Right, my code now looks like 
`$.getJSON('elements/'+countryName+'/data/datafile.js', function(data) {
     $('.welcomeOne h1').html(dt_welcome[0].Translation);
    });`
, however it does not appear to have made any difference!

Comment: without the var 'dt_welcome' part how will it know which object I am trying to access, I have about 20 different ones in that file.

Comment: can you post the content of datafile.js

Comment: Well given the size of the data it would be easier to use $.getScript instead of JSON, Check the last edit on my post and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Edited after looking at the code...

It doesn't look like the js file is json format.  You'll want to use:

```
$.getScript('/[path]/' + language + 'datafile.js', function() {
```

Also, your javascript has a few errors starting on line 187.  Full bullet point is missing quotes.

You can troubleshoot this with Firebug (or Chrome or IE) by just including the script file like normal and looking for errors.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/[path]/england/datafile.js""></script>
```

Once you get those two worked out, it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot post a location to the files as the datafile contains client information, I agree it would have been a lot easier! :(

Comment: Now it has been debranded, here is a link to the files: http://userspace.co.uk/jsontest/ :)

Comment: Sorry to take so long to get back.  New to SO, and thought it would email me or something.